# What is the purpose of testing $DISPLAY with [ -z $DISPLAY ]?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, test

In the very beginning of a script stands:

```
if [ -z $DISPLAY ]
then
  DIALOG=dialog
else
  DIALOG=Xdialog
fi
```

---

I understand, that

- `$DISPLAY` holds the value of which pseudo-terminal one is attached to
- `[ -z $DISPLAY ]` tests whether $DISPLAY has a value or is an empty string

---

What is the purpose of `$DISPLAY` keeping a value, what is different when it has an empty string?
Why would it be crucial for the further execution of the script to know whether `[ -z $DISPLAY ]` is true or false ?

Comment: I was going to say something about the variable being unquoted, but then I realized that, horrible as it is, it actually works even without quotes (as long as `$DISPLAY` expands to at most one word of course)

Comment: I do not understand, can $DISPLAY have more values divided by space characters, because I thought one can only be connected to one pts ?

Comment: I meant that test in general, not specially with `DISPLAY`. I don't think it usually contains more than one word, but of course someone could set it to anything. Also, it's about X, not pseudoterminals.

Comment: maybe I am wrong, I only read one source about it, which i can not estimate for adequacy. however I read, that $DISPLAY contains, if set the symbol for a pseudoterminal, mostly 0:0.0 , please correct me

Comment: @sharkant Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/432257/963

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever this script is, it's using the `$DISPLAY` value to determine if it's running in an X11 environment or not (if the script is running in e.g. a desktop environment, `$DISPLAY` will be set). It doesn't care about the actual value at all.

- If it is running in X11, it sets `DIALOG` to `Xdialog`, which presumably is a X11 program for displaying dialog boxes.
- If it's not running in X11 (for example, it's on a headless machine or in an SSH-session), it sets `DIALOG` to `dialog`, which presumably is a curses (or at least text-based) program for displaying dialog boxes.

Later, the script may use `$DIALOG` to display a dialog box appropriate for the user.